# Blueprint's Select Component onItemSelect trigger on 'Tab' key

Tags: blueprintjs

The onItemSelect callback method for Blueprint's select component gets triggered only when an option is clicked or the 'enter' key is pressed. I would like it to be triggered when the 'Tab' key is pressed too.

```html
    const DropSelect = Select.ofType<IDropdownOption>();
    <DropSelect
            onItemSelect={onItemSelect}
    />
```

Comment: Having tab select an item in the dropdown, means you would remove the standard use of the tab key, which is to switch focus to other focusable elements on the page. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yeah, the tab key's primary function needs to be replaced just when there are drop-downs on the form. Is there a way to do that?